# C# Razor : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, iis, windows-server, windows-server-2012

Estimada Comunidad por favor su apoyo, tengo un problema al publicar mi aplicación de C# Raizor MVC Net4.0 / Net4.6.1, en mi PC local con Windows 10 en Español funciona perfectamente, el problema ocurre cuando a mi aplicativo lo publico en un servidor web AWS con Windows Server 2008 R2 en Ingles EEUU - IIS 7.

El mensaje de error en el navegador es el siguiente:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Estuve investigando, y recomiendan cambiar la configuración en web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" />
```

Alguien me podría ayudar, qué se debe hacer para solucionar este error?.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!
La verdad es que necesitaría más información sobre tu error, como algo de la parte del código dónde declaras la variable, que utilizas para convertirla, el valor que le asignas, etc.
Sin embargo, quizás te sea útil este artículo en inglés que habla de utilizar `DateTime.ParseExact()` en vez de `DateTime.Parse()`. Te dejo el enlace:

[String was not recognized as a valid DateTime “ format dd/MM/yyyy”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193012/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

**Actualizado:**
Viendo el código que me mandas en el comentario, deduzco que lo más probable es porque no puede convertir a `DateTime` un string vacío. El problema está en que si la fecha es `null` le dices que te convierta a fecha `string.Empty`, y eso no puede convertirlo a fecha. Es muy probable que eso es lo que lance la excepción. Algo que se me ocurre, según lo que quieras es que pongas que, en caso de que sea `null`, te defina la fecha mínima. Puedes utilizar `DatTime.MinValue`. Vamos, que puedes dejar algo así:

```
eEntity.fecha_operacion = DateTime.Parse((dtrQuery["fecha_operacion"] == null) ? DateTime.MinValue.ToString() : dtrQuery["fecha_operacion"].ToString());
```

O mejor así:

```
eEntity.fecha_operacion = dtrQuery["fecha_operacion"] == null ? DateTime.MinValue : dtrQuery["fecha_operacion"];
```

Me dices con lo que sea, pero ya te digo que por lo que veo el problema está en lo que te comento: pasar como parámetro a `DateTime.Parse()` un `string.Empty`.

Me comentas con lo que sea. ¡Espero haber sido de ayuda!

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Mi codigo es el siguiente: `eEntity.fecha_operacion = DateTime.Parse((dtrQuery["fecha_operacion"] == null) ? string.Empty : dtrQuery["fecha_operacion"].ToString());`

Comment: ¡Buenas @DAES! He actualizado la respuesta que puse a tu pregunta tomando ahora en cuenta los datos de tu código que me has aportado. A ver si te sirve. Con lo que sea me dices de nuevo y a ver que tal. ¡Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @cjimenecue, aún sigo buscando la sintaxis, en mi local funciona bien el problema ocurre cuando lo pasan a producción, he intentado también pasar primero a una variable de texto y luego esta variable convertirla a fecha y también con la sintaxis que me sugieres pero igual me sale error, por mi parte solo veo los errores en el navegador que es donde tengo acceso. consulta como puedo testear el código cuando ya esta en prod server web IIS 7.5 . para ver exactamente donde esta el error, en el navegador el mensaje de error solo me sale "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

Comment: Dejo por acá la solución a mi problema, en caso les pase el mismo problema, a mi me hizo perder un buen tiempo, El problema estaba en el server, se quedo pegado con una versión anterior, reiniciaron el servidor y funciono correctamente.